# Tricky question regarding application to differentiation but not sure how to begin

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've been struggling with this for a while now. Previous questions completed were regarding maxima and minima but this seems slightly different so am unsure how to approach it.

Question is as follows:

The top of a water tank is a horizontal rectangle, $15\text{ft}$ by $10\text{ft}$, and its base is a square of side $5\text{ft}$ in a parallel plane; its sides are plane and its depth is $12\text{ft}$. Prove that the area of the horizontal plane-section $x\text{ft}$ above the base is $\frac{25}{72}(x+6)(x+12)\text{sq. ft}$ and find the capacity of the tank in $\text{cu.  ft.}$

Solution gives $950\text{cu. ft.}$

I'm sorry I have no working but I'm not sure where to begin with the proof and can therefore not calculate answer. I've tried sketching this and after some thought have come to the conclusion that this isn't a frustum (square base with rectangular top so not sure what to call it) so there is no formula I'm aware of for volume or surface area. I have tried to derive one but to no avail. I was going to integrate derived expression for area (if I could have derived it) but the text book hasn't reached integration yet so as this is a section on applications to differentiation then I'm guessing this is the way forward.

As always, many thanks in advance for any advice given.

Comment: It is not extremum problem. The only need for calculus is integration of cross-section area over height. As sides of tank are planes, and top and base are parallel, so sides of top rectangle and base square are parallel. Then every horizontal cross-section is rectangle. One can find its size using geometry, and express area in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Hopefully you'll get it from my drawings. The cross-section at height $x$ from the base will be a rectangle.  To find the sides of that rectangle let's look at vertical cross-section.

There, $2RS=KL$ and we have that $\frac{RS}{5}=\frac{QJ+x}{QJ+12} \ $ (similar triangles)

Also $\frac{2.5}{5}=\frac{QJ}{QJ+12} \implies 2QJ=12+QJ \implies QJ=12$

Thus, $RS=\frac{5}{24}(12+x), KL=\frac{5}{12}(12+x)$

Similarly, $LM=\frac{5}{6}(6+x)$

To find volume we need to calculate $\int \limits_0^{12}\frac{25}{72}(x+6)(x+12)dx=950$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed solution, it obviously took time to complete the drawings but I can follow them together with your solution. My only question is regarding the tank itself. Is the an official name for this 3D object, I don't think it's a frustum but I'm not sure. Many thanks once again.

Comment: @GRL Drawings are the keys to open geometry. Glad they were helpful.  This tank is still going to be a frustum which is part of a solid between two parallel planes.

Comment: This is where my lack of knowledge is no doubt shining through as I openly admit that my knowledge is very limited in this area but I don't understand how this is a frustum. Surely if it is then the formula for the volume of a frustum would answer the second part of the question. My arithmetic may be wrong but it doesn't appear to. Perhaps I'm getting too bogged down with definitions, just like to be sure of things that's all. Thanks again